# How to set Chart data aand label from the json data

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 . I have a simple bar chart in my project . I want to change the chart data and label with the data from the json .

In my component page I used ..

```js
constructor(private http : Http){
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.100:8000/json1')
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(data =>{ this.result = data
      this.a = JSON.stringify(this.result.map(item=>item.month));
      this.b = JSON.stringify(this.result.map(item=>item.value));
      
    }); 
  }
   type = 'line';
data = {
  
  labels: this.a,
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    data: this.b
  }] 
};
options = {
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
};
```

In my html page

```html
<chart type="bar" [data]="data1" [options]="options"></chart>
```

my json file is look like

```html
[
 {
   "month":"Jan",
   "value":"35"
 },
 {
   "month":"Feb",
   "value":"85"
 }
]
```

But it will not display anything..

Is there any possible solution for this..??

Comment: Which data type expects your input named data.labels and data.datasets.data in the chart component? At the moment a string is passed.

Comment: I Used string type , like .. public a: string;public b: string;

Comment: I guess that's for the component, which uses the chart component. I guess the chart component expects an array. Please try to use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify... and you need to set this.data = in the callback of the get request. Furthermore you need to inform the change detector that there are changes. changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(). In order to do you need to inject changeDetectorRef into the component.

Comment: Btw. API looks like chartjs. Correct?

Comment: It works ..! Thank you@ Henri . Label and Data  must be in array.